# How to sum sub-strings in string separately in Python

Tags: python

this is string of numbers `"72102450111111090"`

I want 4 substrings: 721, 245, 111111, and 9 and sum all of them one by one ie sum of first substring is: 10, second: 11, third: 6 and so on

Comment: `print([sum(int(c) for c in substr) for substr in s.strip('0').split('0')])`

Comment: What have you tried so far?  It looks like a good place to start might be to use `split("0")` on your input

Answer (score 0):

Below is the solution for that

```
all_sums = []
sum = 0
for i in x:
  if i == "0":
    all_sums.append(sum)
    sum = 0
  else:
    sum += int(i)
print(all_sums)
```

Output

```
[10, 11, 6, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the string on the "0" character and filter out empty substrings.  In a comprehension add up the digits of the substrings that you convert to integer individually using map.

```
S = "72102450111111090"

sums = [sum(map(int,ss)) for ss in filter(bool,S.split("0"))]

print(sums)
# [10, 11, 6, 9]
```